# dropdown is not working with bootstrap4 with sass

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, navbar, dropdown

i have written this following code for bootstrap4 but then the toggle functionality doesnt work

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Template</a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                                </div>
  </li>
```

i have included the popper.js too but then it doesnt work out

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" ></script>
```

actually i dont wanna us popper js as i wanna import this framework to vue else there will be conflict

```
can anyone letme know any help would be appreciated
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.dropdown {
 &:hover{
 .dropdown-menu-mn{
   @extend .dropdown-menu;
     display: block;
     opacity: 1;
     overflow: visible;
   }
   }
  }
  .dropdown-menu-mn{
  @extend .dropdown-menu;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

Comment: You need to provide some explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple scss code to toggle in hover.

```
.dropdown{
    &:hover{
       .dropdown-menu{
           visibility: visible;
           opacity: 1;
           overflow: visible;
       }
    }
}
.dropdown-menu{
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: not working overridden styles are not getting applied